# How can I show multi lines in seaborn graph?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I want to draw three lines in seaborn pointplot graph. Three lines are based on the label named for `Total Confirmed, Total Death, Total Recovered`

Here is my dataset

```
      Date     Total Confirmed  Total Death Total Recovered
0   1/22/20         555            17           28
1   1/23/20         654            18           30
2   1/24/20         941            26           36
3   1/25/20         1434           42           39
4   1/26/20         2118           56           52
```

The code I wrote is shown only one value and not shown other two values. How can I fix my code to show all three lines in terms of log graph because their results are different each other.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,7))
ax = sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='Total Confirmed', color="b")
plt.title('General Trend', fontsize=22, y=1.015)
plt.xlabel('month-day-year', labelpad=16)
plt.ylabel('# of people', labelpad=16)
ax.figure.legend()
plt.xticks(rotation=90);
plt.savefig('images/image1.png')
```

Comment: Take a look in this issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050597/matplotlib-plot-multiple-lines-on-the-same-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050597/matplotlib-plot-multiple-lines-on-the-same-chart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the three `pointplot`s separately and add them into the same figure. You can have the y-scale be logarithmic setting `yscale="log"` in `ax.set`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,7))
c=sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='TotalConfirmed', color="b", 
                label='Total Confirmed')
d=sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='TotalDeath', color="r", 
                label='Total Death')
r=sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='TotalRecovered', color="g", 
                label='Total Recovered')
ax.set_title('GeneralTrend', fontsize=22, y=1.015)
ax.set_xlabel('month-day-year', labelpad=16)
ax.set_ylabel('# of people', labelpad=16)
ax.set(yscale="log")
t=plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you need to use melt on the df:

```
df = df.melt("Date", ["Total Confirmed","Total Death","Total Recovered"])
ax = sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='value', hue="variable")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just make other plots in the same figure, like that:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(18,7))

sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='Total Confirmed', color="b")
sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='Total Death', color="g")
sns.pointplot(data = df, x='Date', y='Total Recovered', color="r")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to the ones mentioned is to use the `.plot()` method of a `pandas.DataFrame`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,7))
df.plot(x='Date')
```

You may also provide colors in a dictionary if you want to specify custom colors:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(18,7))
df.plot(x='Date', colors=['r', 'g', 'b'])
```